# How do I make a dog-leg corners in aluminium framing for fly-screens?

Tags: joints, aluminum

I have 20-odd rectangular aluminium (aluminum) windows that need fly-screens.

Sounds easy enough to make my own, but along the bottom edge of each window is a window-winder (280 mm wide and 30mm high) that I need to work around. (This is the real problem I have - if you have another approach to solve this, I am all ears.)

I figured rather than a rectangular fly-screen, I would make a rectangular fly-screen, with a rectangular section cut out of the bottom edge. Slightly more complicated - it requires eight corner inserts, and a bit more care on which edge is the "inside" with the spline. I went and bought enough supplies for one window to make a prototype - including aluminium framing and EIGHT aluminium corner inserts, rather than the four required on most fly-screens.

I soon hit a problem. The rectangle along the bottom edge requires me to turn a corner, and then 30mm later, turn back again, to make a "dog-leg". But 30mm is less than the length of one corner insert, let alone the two I need to insert into the short vertical length of framing.

Here's an example of one of the windows:

[image: Window with winder]
In the bottom left, I have put an off-cut of the aluminium framing, with a corner insert pointing up, so you can see the problem.

Note: While the front of the winding mechanisms bulges up, it slopes back to being square at the back, so there is room for a straight piece. The mechanism is flush with the window when it is closed, so there is no room to go behind the whole mechanism.

If I can't use full-sized corner inserts, how do I secure the framing along the bottom side?

Comment: Many times with casement windows or awning style, the screen are set in an interior perimeter groove so the handle is not needing to be notched around. Check to see if there is a groove top and bottom that would contain an item. Send a pic along to help us visualize what you are working around too please.

Comment: @Jack: I've added a picture. Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably way to late but there's aluminum sill sections you can buy (in Australia at bunnings made by coolaroo).
The winders in my house actually are recessed at the back and are just perfect for the sill section. You just need some tin snips to cut out the sill so it sits perfectly on the winder.
Now if only I can find a way to get perfectly flushed joins on the frame (I think the really cheap mitre I got is causing some issues :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your windows are timber
Normally they have blocks next to the window winder on both sides. 
(The same hight of the winder)
That way your screen sits on the blocks above the winder an your screen is rectangular. 
So all you would have to do is make up some blocks to go next to your winder.

Comment: The windows are aluminium. The winder extends above the glass sill, so to do this would reduce the size of the window. Nonetheless, interesting idea. I am considering how it might apply to my situation.

Comment: You don't have the old screens?

Comment: There are no old screens. (Just moved into 13-year-old apartment that has been empty half its life.)